# How to scroll to top in ISPF Edit or Browse?

Tags: text-editors, mainframe, zos

Is there a command to scroll to the top of of the file in ISPF?  Also, scroll to bottom?

Similar to lower case <kbd>**g**</kbd> in `vi`.

Also, is there anything like scroll to top of function or scroll to opening bracket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the command line type `m` (for max) and the direction you want to go to. So, `:0` would be `m`,.

Alternatively, `top` followed by  will also take you to the top.

Comment: I think m+F7 was what I was trying to remember.  Yours was the closest, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can enter m in the `command line` and hit `up` or `down` pf keys (**Pf7** or **pf8**). You can enter a number on the command line (say 50) and hit *Pf7** or **pf8** to go up/down 50 lines.

There are also use the `top` and `bottom` commands (aliases of `up m` and `down m`) commands (enter in the command line or assign to a pf key).

Finally you could create a rexx macro and enter it on the `Command line` or via a pf key - a bit pointless for something this simple

Comment: I was thinking of the m thing, I like that one.